# How to release netty buffer safely?

Tags: java, buffer, netty

I am using Netty 4.0 and I have read the [Reference counted objects guide](https://github.com/netty/netty/wiki/Reference-counted-objects) that describes normal behavior, but when an exception occurs I have no idea how to release the `ByteBuf`.

eg:

```
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf buf = null;
    if (msg instanceof HttpMessage) {
        if (state != ST_INIT) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("unexpected message type: " + StringUtil.simpleClassName(msg));
        }

        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "CastConflictsWithInstanceof" })
        H m = (H) msg;

        buf = ctx.alloc().buffer();
        // Encode the message.
        encodeInitialLine(buf, m);//
        encodeHeaders(m.headers(), buf);
        buf.writeBytes(CRLF);
        state = HttpHeaders.isTransferEncodingChunked(m) ? ST_CONTENT_CHUNK : ST_CONTENT_NON_CHUNK;
    }

    // Bypass the encoder in case of an empty buffer, so that the following idiom works:
    //
    //     ch.write(Unpooled.EMPTY_BUFFER).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
    //
    // See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/2983 for more information.

    if (msg instanceof ByteBuf && !((ByteBuf) msg).isReadable()) {
        out.add(EMPTY_BUFFER);
        return;
    }

    if (msg instanceof HttpContent || msg instanceof ByteBuf || msg instanceof FileRegion) {

        if (state == ST_INIT) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("unexpected message type: " + StringUtil.simpleClassName(msg));
        }

        final long contentLength = contentLength(msg);
        if (state == ST_CONTENT_NON_CHUNK) {
            if (contentLength > 0) {
                if (buf != null && buf.writableBytes() >= contentLength && msg instanceof HttpContent) {
                    // merge into other buffer for performance reasons
                    buf.writeBytes(((HttpContent) msg).content());
                    out.add(buf);
                } else {
                    if (buf != null) {
                        out.add(buf);
                    }
                    out.add(encodeAndRetain(msg));
                }
            } else {
                if (buf != null) {
                    out.add(buf);
                } else {
                    // Need to produce some output otherwise an
                    // IllegalStateException will be thrown
                    out.add(EMPTY_BUFFER);
                }
            }

            if (msg instanceof LastHttpContent) {
                state = ST_INIT;
            }
        } else if (state == ST_CONTENT_CHUNK) {
            if (buf != null) {
                out.add(buf);
            }
            encodeChunkedContent(ctx, msg, contentLength, out);
        } else {
            throw new Error();
        }
    } else {
        if (buf != null) {
            out.add(buf);
        }
    }
}
```

When `encodeInitialLine(buf, m);` throws an exception, how do I release `buf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your whole method in a try-finally block, and in the finally block, you should check if buf is null or not. If it isn't null, call `buf.release()`.

```
protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    ByteBuf buf = null;
    try {
        ...
    } finally {
        if (buf != null) {
            buf.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when the buf is prepared to writeAndFlush,how to deal with this?

Comment: At the moment you send it using `writeAndFlush`, do `writeAndFlush(buf.retain())`